# javascript calculating difference between two dates gives me NaN

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var startDate = new Date($('#startdate').val());
var endDate = new Date($('enddate').val());
var msPerDay = 1000*60*60*24;
var diff =  Math.floor(startDate.getTime() - endDate.getTime());
$('#period').text(diff/msPerDay);
```

This is my code, it's pretty much based on other answers on SO. I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong here ?

Comment: what is the value of $('#startdate').val()

Comment: 2014-03-19, it's taken from bootstrap's datepicker

Comment: what is teh value of `startDate `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have typo in your code:

Replace `$('enddate').val()` with `$('#enddate').val()`

Answer (score 1):

```
var startDate = new Date($('#startdate').val());
var endDate = new Date($('#enddate').val()); //using id for enddate?
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you meant

```
var endDate = new Date($('enddate').val());
```

and not

```
var endDate = new Date($('#enddate').val());
```

?